# How to make SignalR HttpGet request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I need to make a way for app user to listen to server , and get updated HTTPGET request every time database is updated. Client side implementation is not needed, only server side. I have small experience in SignalR and would appreciate any help on Hub side .
My code so far

Startup

````
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);
            services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Projekt", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Projekt v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<UpdatesHub>("hubs/");
            });
        } ```

here are my ApiCalls user can use
````

````
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ContactsController(IContactRepository contactRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _contactRepository = contactRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }






    #region API CALLS
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppUserDto>>> GetUsers([FromQuery]UserParams userParams)
    {
        //Ego loading phone numbers, gives circular reference problem,
        //use DTOs and Mapping instead

        var users = await _contactRepository.GetUsersAsync(userParams);
        Response.AddpaginationHeader(users.CurrentPage, users.PageSize,
            users.TotalCount, users.TotalPages);
        var usersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AppUserDto>>(users);
        
        return Ok(usersToReturn);
        
    }




    //~/api/Contacts/1
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AppUser>> GetUser(int id)
    {
        var user = await _contactRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(id);
        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<AppUserDto>(user);
        return Ok(userToReturn);
       
    }





    [HttpPost("addContact")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddContact(AppUser appUser)
    {


        var IsConstrained = await _contactRepository.CheckIfConstrained(appUser);
        if (IsConstrained)
        {
            return BadRequest("user already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            _contactRepository.AddContact(appUser);
            var result = await _contactRepository.SaveAllAsync();

            if (result)
                return Ok();
            else
                return BadRequest("user not saved to database");
        }
    }




    [HttpPut("update")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Update(AppUser user)
    {

        //Check if user changed his name, if changed ->check if it's unique then update,
        //if name not changed just update
        var UserBeforeUpdate = _contactRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(user.Id);
        
        var IsNameChangedBool = _contactRepository.CheckIfNameChanged(user , UserBeforeUpdate.Result);
       
        if (IsNameChangedBool)
        {
            var IsConstrained = await _contactRepository.CheckIfConstrained(user);
            if (IsConstrained)
            {
                return BadRequest("user already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                _contactRepository.Update(user);
                if (await _contactRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return Ok("Contact updated");
                return BadRequest("user not saved to database");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _contactRepository.Update(user);
            if (await _contactRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return Ok("Contact updated");
            return BadRequest("user not saved to database");
        } 
    }  ```
````

This is Hub part i don't know how to send updated httpget request to user

```
{
    public class UpdatesHub : Hub
    {

        
        public async Task SendMessageToCaller()
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("RecieveMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, be sure that the route to your hub is correct. For example, if your hub is in the *hubs* folder you need to add `endpoints.MapHub<UpdatesHub>("/hubs/hubName");`

Clients can connect to SignalR in your javaScript with:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/hubs/hubName").build();
```

The clients can subscribe to messages sent from the server. Something like that:

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
    alert(message);
});
```

Create or modify an overloaded constructor of the class in which the database update function is implemented, in order to access the hub:

```
...

public class DatabaseClass
{
     private IHubContext<UpdatesHub> _hub;
     public DatabaseClass(IHubContext<UpdatesHub> hub)
     {
           _hub = hub;
     }

...
```

Now you can use the hub to send a message to the clients, after updating your database:

```
...

public class DatabaseClass
{
     private IHubContext<UpdatesHub> _hub;
     public DatabaseClass(IHubContext<UpdatesHub> hub)
     {
          _hub = hub;
     }

     public MyUpdateFunction()
     {
         //Update database
         //
         //
         _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Database updated!!");
     }

...
```